# Select last duplicate row with different id Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table that look like this:

[image]

The problem is I need to get the last record with duplicates in the column "NRODENUNCIA".

Comment: tables don't actually have an order so you'll need to define what you mean by "last". Also you didn't say do you want the "last" duplicated record or do you want the "last" record per duplicate.

Comment: exactly, i need the last record per duplicate. my english is not very good ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions for your problem. One is to use row_number.

Note that I've ordered by DENUNCIID in the OVER clause. This defines the "Last Record" as the one that has the largest DENUNCIID. If you want to define it differently you'd need to change the field that is being ordered.

```
with dupes as (

SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by NRODENUNCIA ORDER BY DENUNCIID DESC) RN,
        *
FROM 
     YourTable
)
SELECT * FROM dupes where rn = 1
```

This only get's the last record per dupe.

If you want to only include records that have dupes then you change the where clause to

```
WHERE  rn =1 
  and NRODENUNCIA  in (select NRODENUNCIA from dupes where rn > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX(DENUNCIAID)`, along with `GROUP BY... HAVING` to find the duplicates and select the row with the largest `DENUNCIAID`:

```
SELECT MAX(DENUNCIAID), NRODENUNCIA, FECHAEMISION, ADUANA, MES, NOMBREESTADO
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY NRODENUNCIA, FECHAEMISION, ADUANA, MES, NOMBREESTADO
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

This will only show rows that have at least one duplicate.  If you want to see non-duplicate rows too, just remove the `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`

Comment: Given the sample data this works but it won't work when the whole row isn't duplicated

Comment: @ConradFrix Yep.